# Do the level sets of a subharmonic function have measure zero?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose $u$ is subharmonic, real valued and continuous in the open disk $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ and is non constant on any open set in $D$. By adding a constant to $u$ if necessary, I want to know whether the set
$$
\{z\in D: u(z)=0\}
$$
has measure zero?

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a compact set with positive measure, empty interior, and connected complement (e.g., [a simple curve of positive area](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/460844) or a "thick" Cantor-type set).  Let $\mu$ be the equilibrium measure of $K$, i.e., the measure that maximizes the energy 
$$
I(\mu) = \iint \log|z-w|\,d\mu(z)\,d\mu(w)
$$
among all probability measures supported on $K$. Such a measure exists: see, e.g., section 3.3 of *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane* by Ransford or [these lecture notes by Saff](https://www.emis.de/journals/SAT/papers/14/14.pdf). Moreover (from the same sources), the *potential* of $\mu$, defined by
$$
P_\mu(z) = \int \log|z-w|\,d\mu(w)
$$
is

1. subharmonic on $\mathbb{C}$
2. harmonic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$
3. equal to $I(\mu)$ a.e. on $K$

Property 2 implies $P_\mu$ is not constant on any open set, since such a set would overlap $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$, and a harmonic function can't be constant on an open subset of a connected open set unless it's identically constant (recall that harmonic functions are real-analytic).

Comment: Sorry, was unclear - I actually want $u$ not to be open on any open set. Nice example though.

Comment: Answer is still no, however.

Comment: Nice! My original motivation was the study of the resolvent norm of a bounded operator on a separable Hilbert space (for bounded operators the resolvent norm satisfies the above properties). Do you know if this can be converted? I.e. is there an operator such that $P_\mu(z)$ is locally $\left\|(z-T)^{-1}\right\|$ around K?