# Is there a continuous and injective function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ such that the image has positive two dimensional Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Is there a continuous and injective function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ such that the image has positive two dimensional Lebesgue measure?

I am not sure how to approach here. I think ine way to approach this would be by contradiction. I think that we must use the fact that a contiuous bijective map from a campact set to a Hausdorff set is a homeomorphism. However, I am not sure what to do here. If only the property of being positive Lebesgue measure were a topological property...

Comment: Look up the Osgood curve

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti thank you, but how can we prove that it has positive measure? Do you know of any simpler one? Any link would be great

Comment: Another example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460844/a-simple-curve-of-positive-area.

Comment: The boundary of the Mandelbrot set might qualify...