# Lebesgue measure for the graph of a continuous function $f \colon A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: lebesgue-measure

My guess is that I must prove that $A \times \mathbb{R}^m$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$.

Now, knowing that f is continuous on A, whatever succesion $\{x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $\{x_n\} \to x \implies f(\{x_n\}) \to f(x)$ (i.e.: $f(x_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^m$).

Can we take $C_n = \{(x_n,f(x_n)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$ as a cover for $A \times \mathbb{R}^m$? Can I prove that $\sum vol(C_i) < \varepsilon$?

Thank you

Comment: I'd look at proving that some small neighborhood of a point on the graph has measure zero, and then use the fact that a countable union of measure-zero sets has measure zero.

Comment: Not sure about this measure zero thing, there are continuous functions mapping unit segment to unit square in  $R^2$ so called Peanno Curve.

Comment: The term "Lebesgue Measure Zero" refers to a collection of sets X that have a numerable covering and whose "volume" is less than a certain, arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$

Answer (score 2):

Be careful! The graph of $f$ is *not* $A \times \mathbb{R}^m$ in general. You might be saying that the graph is *contained* in this set, so if we can show $A \times \mathbb{R}^m$ is null, then the graph must be too, but this might be false! As a cute exercise, you might try to show this, but I'll leave a big hint below the fold:

> Consider *any* $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Then you're suggesting we consider the set $[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. Can you show this set has infinite measure?

As is mentioned in the comments, we also can't rely on the *image* of $f$ being small! After all, there are continuous injective functions from $\mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ whose images have positive measure! See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460844/a-simple-curve-of-positive-area), for instance.

So then we'll have to use some special property of the graph. One that comes to mind is that it's "sparse" in the sense that, for a fixed $x \in A$, there is *exactly one* $y$ so that $(a,y)$ is in the graph. We can leverage this, and let's see how:

---

Let $\Gamma = \{ (a,f(a)) \mid a \in A \}$ be the graph of $f : A \to \mathbb{R}^m$ for $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, let $\chi_\Gamma$ be the characteristic function of $\Gamma$.

Then if $\mu^d$ is the $d$-dimensional lebesgue measure, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\mu^{m+n} \Gamma
&= \int \chi_\Gamma \ d \mu^{m+n} \\
&= \int \chi_\Gamma \ d (\mu^m \times \mu^n) \\
&\overset{(1)}{=} \int \left ( \int \chi_\Gamma(x,y) \ d \mu^n(y) \right )\ d \mu^m(x) \\
&\overset{(2)}{=} \int \mu^n(\{f(x)\}) \ d\mu^m(x) \\
&= \int 0 \ d \mu^m(x) \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

where in step $(1)$ we've applied (the unsigned version of) Fubini's Theorem, and in step $(2)$ we've evaluated the inner integral. We're thinking of $\chi_\Gamma(x,y)$ as a function of $y$ with fixed $x$. But *this* is where we use the "sparseness" I alluded to earlier! For fixed $x$ there's exactly one choice of $y$ for which $\chi_\Gamma(x,y) \neq 0$: namely $y = f(x)$. So this integral evaluates to the measure of $\{ f(x) \}$, which is (of course) $0$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Nice answer! By the way, you are only using that the function is measurable, not continuous, right?

Comment: @RichardJensen. That's right. Any measurable function should do. There might be some subtleties about the $m+n$-dimensional lebesgue algebra not being the same as the product algebra of the $m$ and $n$ dimensional ones, (the issue is only a matter of nullsets), so let's say "borel measurable" to be safe

Comment: I'm checking this out with some friends and those were the same insights I received! Thank you so much :3. My new idea is: Showing a particular coordinate function $f_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is M. Zero, and then looking if the cartesian products of all f is

Comment: Hi! I'm reading into the aid you gave me, and I have a question:

When you wrote "This integral evaluates to the measure of $\{f(x)\}$, which is zero", does that mean the measure of the image of an m-dimensional function is zero?

Comment: No. There are continuous injective functions from a low dimension space to a high dimension space whose images have positive measure